# How to make the FIND function in Excel ignore case sensitivity?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

Say I have an Excel sheet of 100 records where there are 3 columns `A`, `B` and `C`.

The requirement is I have to get all the rows from column `C` if the text in column `C` matches with `SQL Server`.

Here the text `SQL Server` is in different formats `SQL Server`,`sql Server`,`sql server`

I used the command `=IF(ISERROR(FIND("SQL Server", C2)), 1, 0)` to find the matching rows in column `C`.

If a match is found it returns `0` otherwise it returns `1`.

Now the problem is it is returning `1` for strings like `sql server` and `sql Server`.

How do I make the `FIND` command case insensitive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("sql server",LOWER(C2))),1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks Silx also I tried this way =IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("sql server",LOWER(C2))),1,0) is this correct way? I could see all the field values matching with sql server are resulting 0 irrespective of the case.

Comment: `FIND` is case sensitive, `SEARCH` is not (and can use wild cards) so you could use =IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("SQL Server",C2)),1,0)

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled here looking for something else but the solution is buried so may as well post it here:

Use SEARCH instead of find.  FIND and SEARCH are identical functions other than that SEARCH isn't case sensitive.